# how to pass multiple values from Html Action Link control capturing from user entered text box and send to Action method?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginId, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoginId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">            
        @Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login1", null, new { @class = "link" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And this the javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('.link').click(function () {
        var loginid = $("#LoginId").val();
        var pass = $("#Password").val();
        this.href = this.href + '?loginid=' + encodeURIComponent(loginid);
        this.href = this.href + '?password=' + encodeURIComponent(pass); // Something is going wrong here!
    });
});
```

And this is the Controller Action method:

```
public ActionResult Login1(string loginid,string password)
{
    if (loginid == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    User user = db.Users.Find(loginid);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
}
```

I have entered loginid=a and password=b.
But the problem is:it is sending the loginid =:a?password=b  and password=null.
How can I send the parameter properly?

Comment: The 2nd one needs to be `&password=` (not `?`). But are you seriously passing a password as a url parameter. Suggest you reconsider this and use a form.

Comment: Perfect!Yes, I will be improving that for sure.Any suggestions Sir?

Comment: Change you link to a submit button and post to a `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Login(XXX model)` method (where `XXX` is the model your using in the view). Somehow I don't think that your users will be too happy that your exposing their passwords :)

Answer (score 0):

make the button to submit button and the form will post automatically on click you wont have to write any other code.

make sure that your textbox names(not ids) matches the parameter names in your action.

Answer (score 0):

I think, and i'm no pro, that the error is in the ajax function. The '?' is causing the problem. Current is as follows:

```
this.href = this.href + '?loginid=' + encodeURIComponent(loginid);
this.href = this.href + '?password=' + encodeURIComponent(pass);
```

But should rather be:

```
this.href = this.href + '?loginid=' + encodeURIComponent(loginid);
this.href = this.href + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(pass);
```